# How can I remove a number from a list of strings and find unique instances?

Tags: powershell

Our product consists of multiple WCF services that log some data to CSV files. Each service writes to its own set of files, where the files are named using a sequence number. For example:

```
Product.ServiceA1.csv
Product.ServiceA2.csv
Product.ServiceA3.csv
Product.ServiceB1.csv
Product.ServiceB2.csv
Product.ServiceB3.csv
```

The files are all written to a common folder, `D:\Product\log`.

I'm writing a script to process all the files for each service, and want to identify the results by service name, like so:

```
ServiceA: 25
ServiceB: 30
```

I've come up with the following PowerShell code to get me a list of the distinct service names, but was wondering if anyone has a better way.

```
# Get a list of all the file names; remove the 'Product' prefix and CSV file
# extension so we get just the base name.
$services = get-childitem $logFiles -Name | foreach { $_.Split(".")[1]}

# Remove all the sequence numbers and get a list of the unique names.
$services = [regex]::replace($services,'\d{1,3}','').split(" ") | get-unique
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do an "all-in-one" with regex.

```
$services = (Get-Childitem -Path $logFiles -Name) -replace '(?:.+?)([^\.0-9]+)(?:\d+)(?:\.csv)', '$1' | Get-Unique
```